# Need help with configuration of a touch sensing lamp project!

Tags: capacitance, light, touchscreen, lighting

I am currently a design student in university, and am attempting to configure a large scale project for my final. The idea is that there would be a lamp, with one person holding onto either (wire? something? I have no clue how it would work) and it would turn on once two people touched their hands together to "complete" the circuit. Is there any insight into how this could work? I was thinking of using capacitive touch, or a touch sensor from a lamp, but need to somehow figure out how it could work that both touch sensors need to be touched in order to turn the lamp on. Any help or resources would be great!

Answer (score 1):

Seems too simple for a graduate EE project, but I guess this is the wrong field (no pun intended) , but you would learn about ESD protection and impedance ratios vs f with stray interference.

If you just use line frequency to detect lamp on, you will find lots of stray line interference, and less reliable with lack of ground specs.

If you model each person holding hands as 100pF for a fingertip and 1nF //< 1 Meg then scale x N in series , choose a frequency and filter that will notch very high line E-fields (>100Vac say) and very low signal current with BPF with 4kV ESD protection to detect current  of 50uA at sufficiently low impedance with your model but high Z for RF, AM etc. Work out the right f at Z(f) with specs 1st and the right amount of hysteresis.

An RLC Frequency Nomograph will help visualize the Impedances needed but using RC Active filters.  There are many free tools for doing Bode Filter Design plots. TI, Falstad afilter site, or your favourite software. The best tool is the one you learn how to use.

Comment: Maxwell is studying "Design" rather than "Electrical Engineering Circuit Design."  In this case, "Design" equates to "make stuff that looks cool but is probably impractical."

Comment: Every project can be defined by specs and translated from cool effects from inputs and outputs into engineering terms with tolerances with known interference and variables, and applying 1st principles. But making it reliable and simple might be easy with an Ohmmeter or RLC impedance measurement @f or have false triggers that can be filtered out.

Comment: What I'm saying is that you are discussing technical details with a person who has no concept of what you are talking about.  This is a designer - a person whose job is literally "think up ways to make things look cool."  They aren't taught much about technology, only about appearance. Every word about technical anything in your post went whizzing right by Maxwell's head - he doesn't have the concepts to connect **any** of that to his task.

Comment: Yes. If he has no clue how things work, maybe it’s better he learn or consider something else that he can understand how it works to satisfy the beneficial requirements of Design: Solves a major need, cost-effective, safe, environmentally-friendly excites an audience and fun to make.

Answer (score 0):

This will work with a simple conductance circuit.  Isolated, low voltage, low current:

1 - 5 volt wall wart (USB charger, etc.)

1 - Small solid state relay

1 - 2N7000 transistor

1 - 1 megohm resistor

1 - small piece of perf board

Does this sound like something you can handle?